# Does one ride "in" a chariot, or "on" a chariot?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Is the proper term for riding a chariot "on" or "in"?

Answer (score 2):

One rides in a chariot.

Sources:

- [Man in a Chariot Episode](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0583971/)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chariot#India)
- [2 Kings 9, and 10:16](http://bible.knowing-jesus.com/topics/Chariots)

Thanks @josh61 for this link showing that while "riding on a chariot" has been used, it's always been much less common: [Google Books Trends](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ride%20in%20a%20chariot%2C%20ride%20on%20a%20chariot&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cride%20in%20a%20chariot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cride%20on%20a%20chariot%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Ride in a chariot vs ride on a chariot: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ride+in+a+chariot%2C+ride+on+a+chariot&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cride%20in%20a%20chariot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cride%20on%20a%20chariot%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

Or one rides on a chariot.

Sources:

- *The Material Life of Northern India*
- *Varari on Theater*
- *Iconclass: an iconographic classification system*

Both prepositions are used, with "in" much more popular than "on" per the Ngram Viewer.  I suppose you'd choose based on how enclosing the vehicle was.

Comment: Haha!  So I guess one does whatever one likes with a chariot!  +1, by the way.